# split string with delimiter and put it in some label

Tags: javascript, html

I have a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/yzBKn/3/)

In the demo i have a `table` and a `temp` var to keep the delimited string, using js I am putting the delimited strings into appropriate places, but instead of an input box, i want some `label` i.e., without any boundary or box holding the value. Is there a way to do that, I am using jsp

**for eg**:

**Configuration Name** Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<td width="25%"><input type="text" id="cname" readonly="readonly" style="border:0"></input></td>`

OR

`document.getElementById("cname").innerHTML = config_details[0];`

with either

`<td width="25%"><label" id="cname"></label></td>`

or

`<td width="25%" id="cname" ></td>`

PS: here are the new input types from HTML5

```
search
tel
url
email
datetime
date
month
week
time
datetime-local
number
range
color
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wrtvn/1/)

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="25%">Configuration Name</th>
            <td width="25%"><span id="cname"></span></td>
            <th width="25%">Host Name</th>
            <td id="chostname" width="25%"></td>                
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var temp = "Raj,jh,Production,2011-06-06 08:30:15.0,client1.xml,nix1,abc,Linux"

config_details = temp.split(",");
document.getElementById("cname").innerHTML = config_details[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like <strike>`<input type="label"></input>`</strike>

So you can do something like this.

Change <strike>`<td width="25%" id="cname"><input type="label"readonly="readonly"></input></td>`</strike> to `<td width="25%" id="cname"></td>` and call it like

```
document.getElementById("cname").innerHTML= config_details[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the values into any kind of element you want. Just give the `id` (e.g. `cname`) to the element you want to put the value in and then use `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`, e.g.:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="25%">Configuration Name</th>
            <td width="25%" id="cname"></td>
            <th width="25%">Host Name</th>
            <td width="25%" id="chostname"></td>                
        </tr>
        <!-- ... -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
config_details = temp.split(",");
document.getElementById("cname").innerHTML = config_details[0];
// ...
document.getElementById("chostname").innerHTML = config_details[5];
// ...
```